# Eclipse doesn't find some libraries when using "Add JARs", does find them if using "Add external JARs"

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, libraries

I'm trying to add some libraries to my Java project. My IDE is Eclipse. Visiting

> Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

enables me to add libraries to my project. If I'm using `Add External JARs`, I can find all of my libraries (screenshot below).

[image]

However, if I'm trying to do the same while using `Add JARs`, I get a completely different screen (**the library listed isn't even there!**):

[image]

I'm 100% sure that I'm browsing the correct directories. It seems like there's a cache problem with Eclipse or something like that.

I'm appreciating all suggestions on how to solve this problem. Perhaps a workspace-wide settings reset might be in place?

Comment: When using "Add JARs", it only shows the libraries that are NOT already added to the project. Are you sure the missing JARs are not already added somehow ?

Comment: @DavidLevesque Yes, I'm 100% sure. Manually opening `.classpath` and inserting the libraries worked, but it's still quite a pain :-)...

Comment: Did you try to do a "File -> Refresh" on the project ?

Comment: @DavidLevesque Yes, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

With `Add Jars` option you are able to add all the jars which are there in `present workspace`
With `Add External Jars` you are able to add the jars from the `file system`.

Comment: Correct, but using different methods (add jars, add external jars), but browsing the same folder yields different results. (take a look at the screenshots)

Comment: please refer David Levesque comment

Answer (score 0):

'Add Jar' -> Adds the source of a jar from your workspace

'Add External jar' -> Adds an external .jar or .zip file (something that is not found in your workspace)

'Add Library' -> Adds installed libraries found on your system or in Eclipse